# Unable to open/install 12.04 after downloading

Tags: 12.04

I am unable to find a program to open/install Ubuntu 12.04.(extention .iso)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Furious ISO Mount?
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/furiusisomount/
I think this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Easy use this http://www.linuxliveusb.com/ put it on a usb flash drive and set your pc to boot to USB